# Can I use Python SDK to access data from azure datalake gen2?

Tags: python, azure-data-lake

Python SDK available for Azure DataLake Gen1. the documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-get-started-python)

Can i use same SDK to access files at Azure DataLake Gen2 from python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encounter the same issue, and get the [feedback](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/22913#issuecomment-456717500) from Microsoft:

> Unfortunately these SDKs cannot be used with ADLS Gen2 as of now.
>
> However, I would suggest to keep an eye on [Azure updates](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/?product=storage). Azure
> updates provide information about important Azure product updates,
> roadmap, and announcements.

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented a small library just for own use. It's not working properly with all rest api methods, but I'm always welcome for any help:)  You can check it here: https://github.com/estatic/pydatalake-gen2